# Best solution for sports statistics

Tags: categorical-data, excel, tables

I have created a floorball sports statistics in excel. It works like this: I put in data from each match (mininal required data like who was present and who scored etc.) and then I have sheets which gather these data and creates tables automatically, for players,teams, goalies... together over 400 different stat types. Now, the problem is, that these sheets are made and fixed for maximum 10 teams and 21 players for each team. If I want to add more players I need to manually remake all sheets and largen tables. Is there a way how to do this automatically in excel or is there a better program for this? Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a good way to start programming. Try Python with Pandas. You can even create a parser which will gather the data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly, the answer is "no."  If you have linked the sheets together the way it sounds like you did, then the answer is "no."  Even if you had programmed the sheets in VBA, it would be difficult to do what you describe.

Now for the good news.  Any general purpose programming language can do what you need doing.  Some probably easier than others, but this sounds like a pretty simple task.

R, which is a statistical language, has a structure called a *data frame.*  A data frame is basically a spreadsheet, so it is easy to import spreadsheets to it.  You could then restructure your data from there.

R is hard to learn to do well, but easy to learn to do badly and have it still work fine.

R is difficult to do "fast", but if three seconds versus a tenth of a second is no big deal to you, then doing it badly isn't a problem.

I would import your sheets into data frames using something like R Commander, which I don't use but I do recommend to students.  Look at varying competing books on R and see which seems the easiest for you to learn with.

R Commander imports the data in a way that looks like a spreadsheet.  **You cannot use it as a spreadsheet, it just looks like one.**

If you have four hundred statistics, you have a couple of choices.  First, you can create four hundred different functions minus any standard function such as mean or median.  Second, you can learn to create "objects," which could encapsulate multiple related types of functions in one go.

If you are going to do any reporting with this, also look at R Markdown which converts your results into reports, websites, and so forth.  You can also animate your results with gganimate or just graph them with ggplot2.  The gg stands for "Grammar of Graphics."

R Commander will also build graphs for you in a manner similar to Excel.

R has a steep learning curve but once you get it, the curve is pretty flat.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will dive into it.